# Linq pairing two Lists of different classes with join

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the code below

```
var allA = // holds a List<classA>
var allB = //holds a List<ClassB>
var res = from A in allA
        join B in allB on A.Id equals B.Id
         select new Tuple<string,string,string,string,string>        
            (B.val1,B.val2,A.val1,A.val2,A.val3);

var resList = res as List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string>>;
```

Now the issue is, with the way im doing it I'd have to remember which item in my tuples hold what value. I don't why `resList = res as a List<Tuple<...>>` doesn't work either, it doesn't hold any values.

How can I structure this where I have a `List<Tuple<ClassA,ClassB>>` and in each tuple, ClassA and ClassB are the joined pair in Linq select statement?

Comment: Do you _need_ to use Tuples? Tuples don't help with maintainability. As you've noticed, it's not easy to remember what property represents what. Maybe make your own combined class or use anonymous classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the following two classes and lists

```
class A { 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class B { 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public decimal Size {get;set;}
}

(...) 

var la = new A[]{ new A { Id = 1, Name = "Snake"}, new A { Id = 2, Name = "Adam"}};
            
var lb = new B[]{ new B { Id = 1, Size = 0.8m}, new B { Id = 2, Size = 1}};
```

You can create an object with two properties:

```
var lab = from a in la
          join b in lb on a.Id equals b.Id
          select new {a, b}; // or select new { A = a, B = b};
```

I used anonymous type, but you can create a type the has two properties A and B and use that.

If you wish for a tuple, use a modern tuple with [named fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names):

```
          select (A: a, B: b);
```

Having said that, maybe an object with the properties that you need is the best choice.

```
var lab = from a in la
          join b in lb on a.Id equals b.Id
          select new  
          { 
             Id = a.Id, 
             Name = a.Name,
             Size = b.Size
          };
```